# problem with updating (confilting distribution: deb.opera.com)

Tags: update-manager, opera

When I run update-manager I have this message:

```
W:Conflicting distribution: http://deb.opera.com testing Release 
(expected testing but got stable), 
W:Failed to fetch http://deb.opera.com/opera/dists/lenny/non-free/binaryi386Packages      
404  Not Found, E:Some index files failed to download. 
They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have ignore this in the past since it didn't affect my daily usage of my system. Now that I want to update from 12.04 to 14.04, it wont allow me with the same error message.

I have removed Opera but it didn't seem to help

Ay idea about what would help?
Thanks
Nemo

Comment: just comment out the line starting with `deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/dists` in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to upgrade I would remove the opera repository from your apt sources:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list*
```

Once your system properly upgraded to 14.04, [download](http://www.opera.com/download/guide/?os=linux) and install opera to set up the repo again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but

sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list* rm: cannot remove `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list*': No such file or directoryls

I checked and indeed, there is no "opera" in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

Could it be somewhere else? Thanks Nemo

Comment: Look in your main sources.list: `/etc/apt/sources.list` and remove all lines containing `opera`

Comment: You should find the correct list file with `grep -r opera /etc/apt`